# Howto use Google Accounts as login

Tags: android, google-api, google-account

I'm thinking about using Google Accounts as a user verification for a service I'm developing.  This will be a client and server.  I'm hoping to be able to use the already signed-in Google Account on the Android phone and use that as a verification on my server.

Where can I find information about this?

Is it possible to use the already signed-in account on the phone or do I have to re-sign-in in my application?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a class called `AccountManager` which acts like a registry for the users online account. I think this is what you are looking for.

There's also something called [Federated Login for Google](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OpenID.html), which allows users to login using their Google Account. Its more like OpenID

Comment: Is this the same library that the Google Reader App uses? You can see it after launching the Reader app for the 1st time and asks you to authorize the app.

Comment: Ok but Reader app uses it to get your google reader feeds and content. How do I use AccountManager to login user into my system?