# Using Google account as Login... what next?

Tags: android, authentication, account

I'm developing an app for android, that will have an api-like server side. And this app will have users login mechanisms. I want to use a google/fb/twitter account as login information, as the purpose of the app is very socially-spoted.

I have already read about using the Google Account stored in the phone as user verification ( [Howto use Google Accounts as login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4327981/howto-use-google-accounts-as-login) ). Problem is that I don't know what to do then? As I understood, the Account Manager, will finally give me a token. Then what do I do with it? How do I inform the server side that the user did login? How do I store this token, as I understood that this token might change when invalidated after some time...

And another thing. What do I do when user enters his G account for 1st time? I want to get his G avatar and display name, for example and store them on the server,thus saving the user a bunch of clicks? Do I send them somehow from the phone or I get them somehow from the server?

This same questions might arise for FB later, too.

Hope I did ask my question correctly, as this is a little more general question...

TIA.

Answer (score 2):

I think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352592/webservice-credentials-openid-android-accountmanager/13938157#13938157) covers exactly what you're asking.

For me the best solution was covered in [this](http://blog.notdot.net/2010/05/Authenticating-against-App-Engine-from-an-Android-app) blog post. It will only work with Google accounts, and assumes you're using UserService on the AppEngine side, but I think it works well. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Google uses OpenId while FB has its own thing. You'll need different codepaths for those two.

http://www.sozkan.com/blog/2010/09/24/very-quick-openid-integration-tutorial/

Granted - this relies on URLs to manage the data - you'll need to wrap this in your code if you want it all to happen internally. Once you have the token you can notify your server-side code of what it is, lifespan, etc.

Info on differences:
http://thenextweb.com/socialmedia/2010/11/04/facebook-connect-oauth-and-openid-the-differences-and-the-future/

Comment: The question was exactly what is the procedure for a client-server app. For a web-based application this question does not persist, as the only work is done in a single place. Here it is another situation - the user is authenticated on the CLIENT, and the SERVER is not yet aware of that. So how do I actually notify him that the user is authenticated with a particular credentials and how to verify all this and so on and so on...

Comment: You would authenticate via the CLIENT and notify the SERVER once you got the go-ahead - OR - you would do it the other way around - have the client tell the server to authenticate and then send the result back to the client. Most server languages (PHP, JAVA, Perl,etc )support some sort of web communication ( eg Curl ) so that's one avenue for the authentication. Google might also offer a SOAP avenue too.

Comment: Down-voted because HTTP-ing the URLs yourself, by hand, replicates the behavior of AccountManager, AND throws away Android's existing list of logged-in accounts.

Answer (score 0):

Just to finish this (stale) question, and park my code snippet somewhere, I have started to log in with Google using a `PreferenceScreen` Activity with this `onCreate()` code:

```
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile");
    final GoogleAccountCredential credential = 
        GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(getApplicationContext(), list); 
    Preference acctValue = findPreference("GMail");  // A <Preference> in the XML...

    acctValue.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
            startActivityForResult(credential.newChooseAccountIntent(), 1);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

And they required adding these shady characters to my `libs` folder:

```
google-api-client-android-1.17.0-rc.jar
google-play-services.jar
google-api-client-1.17.0-rc.jar
google-http-client-1.17.0-rc.jar
```